# Start IPython session on uncaught error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

With `pry` in Ruby, you are able to start an interactive shell session (also called a read-evaluate-print loop) when an uncaught exception occurs, greatly speeding up debugging.

I've found that for most things, the equivalent to `pry` in Python is `ipython`. Is there a way to do enable the aforementioned feature with `ipython`? Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish this within Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ipython can do this. Native python also has this feature. In unix you can simply write python for interactive shell session. Ipython a higher level instrument - it can store input from your previous session and smth else. If you like GUI, you can install ipython-notebook for interactive programming in you browser.